# Chaotic behaviour of the secant method for $\sin(x)$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos

For not very serious reasons I was trying to understand the behaviour of the secant method for solving $\sin(x)=0$ starting with $x_0=2$ and $x_1=18$, so
$$ x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}-\sin(x_{n+1})\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\sin(x_{n+1})-\sin(x_n)}. $$
The sequence wanders around in a chaotic manner until it randomly happens that $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ are close and there is a number of the form of $k\pi$ in between them; then it converges rapidly to $k\pi$.  I tried to calculate this numerically to high precision and found that I got very different answers when working to different numbers of digits.  However, with $10^4$ digits I got $k=-24660632751539897$ after about $450$ steps, and then I got the same answer with $2\times 10^4$ digits, so it seems reasonable to guess that that is the real answer.  However, I have no idea how to analyse this theoretically.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I can reproduce this with Pari/GP. In my opinion, two possibilities. The first, which I find most probable, is that you also use Pari/GP and there is a bug in the evaluation to very high accuracy of the sine function when the argument is close to a multiple of $\pi$. The second, if you use some other software, is that it may be a true observation.

Comment: I used Maple, not Pari. I don't see any reason to assume that there are bugs, sensitive dependence on initial conditions is a natural feature of this kind of iterative scheme.

Comment: good, then it's a true observation. I don't understand the initial downvote.

Comment: Clearly you’re looking at the dynamical system $(x,y)\mapsto(y,y-(x-y)/(\sin x-\sin y))$. 

Specific dynamical systems tend to be very hard to study unless they have unusual properties (an invariant function, “hyperbolic structure” etc). If not there are some general ideas like Lyapunov exponents that are hard to compute, but give information about stability of orbits etc.

Comment: Secant method involves a 2-term recurrent relation, which makes this problem more difficult then the same with Newton method. Newton method for functions like sine can be completely analyzed on the real line.